# Translation of "Field" (as in, on a form)

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

The online automated translators tend to use `campo` (ie. a field, like a soccer field) for this, but I'm not sure if this appropriate.

What is the proper translation here to refer to a field on a computer form?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Campo` translates seamlessly to all what `field` means in English: a form gap, some sport pitch, a rural zone.

Comment: Even a field of knowledge: un campo de conocimiento.

Answer (score 3):

Campo is OK. You could also use "casillero" or "casilla" in this context.

Comment: +1. Just note that casillero/casilla tend to mean checkbox rather than a field in general.

Answer (score 1):

In Puerto Rico (Castilian-Spanish) the slang "campo" is commonly used, but I use "encasillado", which people here equate to a box.